# woocommerce BACS add custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to put custom BACS field in the Thank you page and also for the emails. My country needs 'variable symbol' for the BACS method, which would be the order number. I dont want to change core files.

This is what i do:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_account_fields', 'custom_bacs_account_field', 10, 2);
function custom_bacs_account_field( $account_fields, $order_id ) {
    $account_fields['variable_symbol'] = array(
        'label' => 'Variabilní symbol',
         'value' => $order_id
    );
    return $account_fields;
}
```

For some reason this displays the variable symbol twice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so this works for me:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_account_fields', 'custom_bacs_account_field', 10, 2);
function custom_bacs_account_field( $account_fields, $order_id ) {
    static $call_counter = 0;
     if ( $call_counter>0 ) {
         return $account_fields;
     }
    $account_fields['variable_number' ] = array(
        'label' => 'Variabliní symbol',
         'value' => $order_id
    );
    $call_counter++;
    return $account_fields;
}
```